# Why is my MSI repairing?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

While launching shortcut (non-advertised) MSI starts a repair.
I want to suppress the repair. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the root cause of the repair. For this [enable logging on the machine](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html) (see method in the lower side of the linked page) and analyze the verbose log generated, it should mention which component key member is missing, thus triggering the automatic repair.

After you identify the component starting the repair you can take action. i.e. remove those resources if you don't need them or make sure they are always available.

Usually this can happen with temporary resources captured form the original installer, for example it is a web installer that downloads some files, installs them and then deletes the downloaded resources.